# Control in control binding

Tags: wpf, user-controls, caliburn.micro

Ok. So I have a main view with the following line

```
<!-- The first one is commented cause I tried it and it failed harder -->
<!--<ContentControl Name="BcModel" Grid.Column="2" Width="300" Height="300"/>-->
<local:BigCalendarDateView x:Name="BcModel" Grid.Column="2" Width="300" Height="300"/>
```

And the ViewModel

```
[Export(typeof(AppViewModel))]
public class AppViewModel : Screen
{
    public BigCalendarDateViewModel BcModel { get; set; }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public AppViewModel(BigCalendarDateViewModel mod, IEventAggregator events)
    {
        this.DisplayName = "Calendar";
        events.Subscribe(this);
        BcModel = mod;
    }
}
```

And for the `BigCalendarDateViewModel`, I have the View

```
<!-- Commented because I tried this also -->
<!--cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ChangeState]"-->
<Button Name="ChangeState" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,156,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138"/>
```

And in the ViewModel

```
[Export(typeof(BigCalendarDateViewModel))]
public class BigCalendarDateViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    ...
    public void ChangeState()
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
}
```

I can debug through, and the AppView, AppViewModel, BigCalendarDateView and BigCalendarDateViewModel all get initialized, and the BigCalendarDateViewModel is displayed visually, but when I click the button, it either says it can't find the method, or it doesn't do anything.

It almost seems like the BigCalendarDateViewModel never gets wired to the BigCalendarDateView.

When I make a bootstrapper for the control, which pops it up in its own window, it works fine(in the new window, not in the first window still)

Any ideas?

Comment: try using x:Name on the button.

Comment: @mdm20 Thanks but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can explicitly provide the viewmodel to the view by doing something like this:

```
<local:BigCalendarDateView Grid.Column="2" Width="300" Height="300" cal:Bind.Model={Binding BcModel} />
```